# How would I get Ubuntu Server to automatically start programs on two virtual terminals?

Tags: server, minecraft, virtual-console

So I have a Minecraft server and a website and I want two things to startup when the computer boots: Minecraft Server and the Minecraft Overviewer. I want the server to startup in tty1 and the overviewer to startup in tty2. (The apache thing starts up fine and runs in the background.) By the way, the overviewer is just a bash script to repeat `overviewer --config ~/overviewer/config` every hour.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>To startup processes in a particular `tty` on startup, you have to edit this file: `/etc/init/tty*.conf`. Replace `*` with the `tty` number. Add your server's startup script to this file. An example may be:</strike>

```
exec /sbin/getty -n -l /path/to/minecraft-server/startup.sh -8 38400 tty1
```

(*This might not let you log in if your script does not explicitly call `/sbin/login`!*)

On retrospect, `openvt` might be more suitable for your needs. Edit your `/etc/rc.local` file and add the `openvt` command.

```
openvt -c 1 sh /path/to/minecraft-server/startup.sh
```

The script will be run on startup automatically @ tty1 this way :)

---

You'll  want to set up a `cron` job for the `overviewer`. `cron` is a program that schedules tasks (that you define/configure) to run at particular intervals. Read more about `cron` [here](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).

A sample `cron` job entry for the `overviewer` might look like:

```
0 * * * * root /path/to/overviewer/overviewer --config ~/overviewer/config
```

This entry will go into the `crontab` file located at `/etc/crontab`.

The format of a `crontab` entry is:

```
minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week user command
```

Hope this helps!